# Finding the measure of a set using Lebesgue Integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let's say I have a Lebesgue integrable function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is an arbitrary measure space. Now, suppose I want to find the measure of the set 
$$
A = \{x \in X: f(x) \geq c\}
$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there a way that I can express 
$\mu(A)$ in terms of $\int f$? Note that $A$ is measurable by definition of a measurable function. I'm not looking for a fancy way to do this; I'm new to this topic and I'm wondering whether there is an easy expression.

Edit 1: If not an exact relationship, is there an inequality?

Comment: There's *a* way to do something somewhat close to this but I'm not sure if you'd like it.. $$\mu(A) = \int_X 1_{\{x:f(x)\ge c\}}(x)\,d\mu(x).$$ (This is just cleverly repackaging the definition of $A$, really..)

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah I'm familiar with indicator functions but I was wondering if there is a (basic) way to express it in terms of $\int f$. Again, I'm new to measure theory so I wasn't sure whether this is an "obvious" property, but it seems like not.

Comment: If you assume that $f$ is the Radon-Nikodỳm derivative of $\mu$, then $\mu(A) = \int_Af(x)\:\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Following Cameron Williams, an inequality is given by 
$\mu(\{f\geq c\})= \int_ {\{f\geq c\}} 1\, d \mu \leq \frac{1}{c} \int f d\mu,$
since $\frac{f}{c} \geq 1$ on $\{f\geq c\}$.